# Comparator fails with given test data - Why?

Tags: java, comparator

I have a problem with a comparator. It works most of the time.  I have created a test where it fails but I cannot see why it fails or what is wrong. It fails with the error of: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

The general situation is a list of fields from a PDF that are being sorted by page then by the Y position and then by the X position.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction as to why this is failing with the given test data.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class DateUtilsTest extends TestCase {
    public void testForDerrick() {
        String fields = "null\t\t27.5118\t\t496.989\n" +
        "null\t\t121.96\t\t192.52\n" +
        "0\t\t79.5814\t\t301.597\n" +
        "0\t\t79.5814\t\t264.662\n" +
        "0\t\t196.29\t\t429.681\n" +
        "0\t\t195.955\t\t314.32\n" +
        "0\t\t196.868\t\t277.982\n" +
        "0\t\t210.99\t\t429.681\n" +
        "0\t\t210.82\t\t277.982\n" +
        "0\t\t225.552\t\t429.681\n" +
        "0\t\t224.029\t\t277.982\n" +
        "0\t\t218.91\t\t198.61\n" +
        "0\t\t267.12\t\t340.05\n" +
        "0\t\t298.85\t\t346.5\n" +
        "0\t\t372.16\t\t384.81\n" +
        "null\t\t349.16\t\t346.5\n" +
        "0\t\t549.35\t\t188.459\n" +
        "0\t\t626.48\t\t457.041\n" +
        "0\t\t649.28\t\t511.764\n" +
        "0\t\t647.456\t\t503.618\n" +
        "0\t\t647.456\t\t477.432\n" +
        "0\t\t658.659\t\t539.6\n" +
        "0\t\t658.659\t\t477.432\n" +
        "0\t\t701.73\t\t474.041\n" +
        "0\t\t712.98\t\t474.041\n" +
        "0\t\t626.48\t\t121.0\n" +
        "0\t\t626.48\t\t41.0\n" +
        "0\t\t662.44\t\t117.0\n" +
        "0\t\t673.611\t\t117.0\n" +
        "0\t\t687.52\t\t117.0\n" +
        "0\t\t700.73\t\t117.0\n" +
        "0\t\t712.98\t\t117.0\n" +
        "0\t\t787.169\t\t150.654\n" +
        "null\t\t123.57\t\t532.77\n" +
        "1\t\t35.6173\t\t92.42\n" +
        "1\t\t47.83\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t47.83\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t76.5\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t76.5\t\t368.85\n" +
        "null\t\t123.57\t\t417.02\n" +
        "1\t\t99.03\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t99.03\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t99.03\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t99.03\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t109.29\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t109.29\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t109.29\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t109.29\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t119.56\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t119.56\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t119.56\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t119.56\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t129.83\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t129.83\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t129.83\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t129.83\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t140.09\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t140.09\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t140.09\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t140.09\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t150.36\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t150.36\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t150.36\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t150.36\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t160.62\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t160.62\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t160.62\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t160.62\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t171.319\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t171.319\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t171.319\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t171.319\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t180.464\t\t401.15\n" +
        "1\t\t192.194\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t192.194\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t192.194\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t202.464\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t202.464\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t202.464\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t202.464\t\t53.0295\n" +
        "1\t\t212.724\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t212.724\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t212.724\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t212.724\t\t53.0295\n" +
        "1\t\t222.994\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t222.994\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t222.994\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t222.994\t\t53.0295\n" +
        "1\t\t233.254\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t233.254\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t233.254\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t233.254\t\t53.0295\n" +
        "1\t\t243.564\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t243.564\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t243.564\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t243.564\t\t242.83\n" +
        "1\t\t243.564\t\t136.83\n" +
        "1\t\t253.874\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t253.874\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t253.874\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t253.874\t\t242.83\n" +
        "1\t\t253.874\t\t136.83\n" +
        "1\t\t264.264\t\t514.83\n" +
        "1\t\t264.264\t\t441.71\n" +
        "1\t\t264.264\t\t369.08\n" +
        "1\t\t264.264\t\t242.83\n" +
        "1\t\t264.264\t\t136.83\n" +
        "1\t\t274.154\t\t400.98\n" +
        "1\t\t285.485\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t285.485\t\t441.444\n" +
        "1\t\t285.485\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t285.485\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t295.802\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t295.802\t\t441.444\n" +
        "1\t\t295.802\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t295.802\t\t149.84\n" +
        "1\t\t295.802\t\t104.36\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t441.444\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t242.29\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t189.18\n" +
        "1\t\t305.576\t\t107.88\n" +
        "1\t\t316.153\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t316.153\t\t441.444\n" +
        "1\t\t316.153\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t316.153\t\t198.06\n" +
        "1\t\t316.153\t\t151.58\n" +
        "1\t\t326.675\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t326.675\t\t441.444\n" +
        "1\t\t326.675\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t326.675\t\t211.5\n" +
        "1\t\t326.675\t\t165.02\n" +
        "1\t\t336.47\t\t401.15\n" +
        "1\t\t347.74\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t347.74\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t347.74\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t347.74\t\t53.2\n" +
        "1\t\t358.13\t\t515.0\n" +
        "1\t\t358.13\t\t441.88\n" +
        "1\t\t358.13\t\t369.25\n" +
        "1\t\t358.13\t\t247.9\n" +
        "1\t\t358.13\t\t153.0\n" +
        "1\t\t368.02\t\t401.15\n" +
        "1\t\t400.19\t\t442.787\n" +
        "1\t\t400.19\t\t368.25\n" +
        "null\t\t123.57\t\t306.57\n" +
        "1\t\t423.977\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t423.977\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t423.977\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t423.977\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t434.237\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t434.237\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t434.237\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t434.237\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t444.507\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t444.507\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t444.507\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t444.507\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t454.777\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t454.777\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t454.777\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t454.777\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t465.037\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t465.037\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t465.037\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t465.037\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t475.307\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t475.307\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t475.307\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t475.307\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t485.567\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t485.567\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t485.567\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t485.567\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t495.837\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t495.957\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t495.957\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t495.957\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t506.847\t\t402.613\n" +
        "1\t\t517.117\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t517.117\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t517.117\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t517.117\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t527.387\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t527.387\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t527.387\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t527.387\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t537.647\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t537.647\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t537.647\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t537.647\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t547.917\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t547.917\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t547.917\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t547.917\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t558.177\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t558.177\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t558.177\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t558.177\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t568.447\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t568.447\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t568.447\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t568.447\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t578.707\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t578.707\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t578.707\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t578.707\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t588.977\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t588.977\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t588.977\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t588.977\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t599.237\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t599.237\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t599.237\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t599.237\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t609.507\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t609.637\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t609.637\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t609.637\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t620.527\t\t402.613\n" +
        "1\t\t630.787\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t630.787\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t630.787\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t630.787\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t641.057\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t641.057\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t641.057\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t641.057\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t651.317\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t651.317\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t651.317\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t651.317\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t661.587\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t661.587\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t661.587\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t661.587\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t671.847\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t671.847\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t671.847\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t671.847\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t682.117\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t682.117\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t682.117\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t682.117\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t692.387\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t692.387\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t692.387\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t692.387\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t702.777\t\t516.463\n" +
        "1\t\t702.777\t\t443.343\n" +
        "1\t\t702.777\t\t369.713\n" +
        "1\t\t702.777\t\t54.6625\n" +
        "1\t\t712.667\t\t402.613\n" +
        "2\t\t131.82\t\t494.835\n" +
        "2\t\t166.95\t\t334.15\n" +
        "2\t\t166.95\t\t311.9\n" +
        "2\t\t180.85\t\t334.15\n" +
        "2\t\t180.85\t\t311.9\n" +
        "2\t\t193.091\t\t334.15\n" +
        "2\t\t204.861\t\t334.15\n" +
        "2\t\t198.31\t\t311.9\n" +
        "2\t\t216.78\t\t334.15\n" +
        "2\t\t216.78\t\t311.9\n" +
        "2\t\t140.206\t\t286.44\n" +
        "2\t\t140.206\t\t250.77\n" +
        "null\t\t90.11\t\t192.52\n" +
        "null\t\t47.83\t\t440.17\n" +
        "null\t\t572.54\t\t197.55\n" +
        "2\t\t140.206\t\t224.243\n" +
        "2\t\t140.206\t\t188.434\n" +
        "2\t\t152.411\t\t190.822\n" +
        "2\t\t166.95\t\t191.0\n" +
        "2\t\t198.31\t\t191.0\n" +
        "2\t\t216.78\t\t191.0\n" +
        "null\t\t166.95\t\t254.0\n" +
        "2\t\t313.6\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t313.6\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t342.27\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t342.27\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t371.07\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t371.07\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t399.87\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t399.87\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t428.67\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t428.67\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t457.47\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t457.47\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t486.27\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t486.27\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t515.07\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t515.07\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t543.87\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t543.87\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t572.67\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t572.67\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t601.47\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t601.47\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t630.27\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t630.27\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t659.07\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t659.07\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t687.87\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t687.87\t\t57.8\n" +
        "2\t\t715.92\t\t501.8\n" +
        "2\t\t715.92\t\t57.8\n" +
        "3\t\t359.57\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t390.22\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t458.086\t\t545.206\n" +
        "3\t\t458.086\t\t478.15\n" +
        "3\t\t458.086\t\t317.306\n" +
        "3\t\t488.85\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t518.65\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t538.809\t\t435.303\n" +
        "3\t\t550.477\t\t435.303\n" +
        "3\t\t568.55\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t581.219\t\t436.03\n" +
        "3\t\t590.989\t\t436.03\n" +
        "3\t\t603.112\t\t436.03\n" +
        "3\t\t620.3\t\t394.05\n" +
        "3\t\t687.503\t\t317.306\n" +
        "null\t\t639.63\t\t117.0\n" +
        "null\t\t650.984\t\t117.0\n" +
        "3\t\t314.184\t\t39.7711\n" +
        "3\t\t336.086\t\t39.7711\n" +
        "3\t\t358.272\t\t39.7711\n" +
        "3\t\t571.296\t\t40.0028\n" +
        "3\t\t599.766\t\t39.8304\n" +
        "3\t\t621.736\t\t39.8304\n" +
        "3\t\t665.499\t\t39.8304\n" +
        "3\t\t687.859\t\t39.8304\n" +
        "4\t\t115.997\t\t503.877\n" +
        "4\t\t115.62\t\t324.0\n" +
        "4\t\t115.62\t\t40.5\n" +
        "4\t\t121.715\t\t215.873\n" +
        "4\t\t188.51\t\t432.749\n" +
        "4\t\t200.49\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t220.99\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t233.98\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t244.96\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t255.95\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t266.94\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t278.92\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t288.55\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t299.294\t\t432.749\n" +
        "4\t\t312.88\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t321.887\t\t432.75\n" +
        "4\t\t188.51\t\t288.75\n" +
        "4\t\t200.49\t\t288.75\n" +
        "4\t\t220.99\t\t288.75\n" +
        "4\t\t233.98\t\t288.75\n" +
        "4\t\t244.96\t\t288.75\n" +
        "4\t\t255.95\t\t288.75\n" ;

        List<TestSort> testSortList = new ArrayList<TestSort>();
        String[] fieldList = fields.split("\n");
        for (String field : fieldList) {
            String[] threeVals = field.split("\t\t");
            TestSort df = new TestSort();
            df.setPage(!"null".equals(threeVals[0]) ? Integer.valueOf(threeVals[0]) : null);
            df.setTopLeftY(Double.valueOf(threeVals[1]));
            df.setTopLeftX(Double.valueOf(threeVals[2]));
            df.setFormField("");
            testSortList.add(df);
        }
        Collections.sort(testSortList, new Comparator<TestSort>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TestSort o1, TestSort o2) {
                if (o1.getPage() == null || o2.getPage() == null || o1.getPage().equals(o2.getPage())) {
                    if (o1.getTopLeftY() == null || o2.getTopLeftY() == null || o1.getTopLeftY().equals(o2.getTopLeftY())) {
                        if (o1.getTopLeftX() == null || o2.getTopLeftX() == null || o1.getTopLeftX().equals(o2.getTopLeftX())) {
                            return o1.getFormField().compareTo(o2.getFormField());
                        } else {
                            return o1.getTopLeftX().compareTo(o2.getTopLeftX());
                        }
                    } else {
                        return o1.getTopLeftY().compareTo(o2.getTopLeftY());
                    }
                } else {
                    return o1.getPage().compareTo(o2.getPage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestSort {
        private Integer page;
        private Double topLeftY;
        private Double topLeftX;
        private String formField;

        public String getFormField() {
            return formField;
        }

        public void setFormField(String formField) {
            this.formField = formField;
        }

        public Integer getPage() {
            return page;
        }

        public void setPage(Integer page) {
            this.page = page;
        }

        public Double getTopLeftY() {
            return topLeftY;
        }

        public void setTopLeftY(Double topLeftY) {
            this.topLeftY = topLeftY;
        }

        public Double getTopLeftX() {
            return topLeftX;
        }

        public void setTopLeftX(Double topLeftX) {
            this.topLeftX = topLeftX;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fairly evident from the question that he wants his comparator not to throw a comparator violates it's general contract exception.

Comment: @Bohemian Also he met all the requirements of your reason for putting it on hold.  "He provided the shortest code necessary to reproduce it" and "a specific...error" he's getting.

Comment: Agree with Uncle; no reason whatsoever to put the question on hold @Bohemian.

Comment: When does it fail? Somewhat unrelated, but that's a hard comparator to reason about--I'd consider refactoring/cleaning.

Comment: @UncleIroh There are 353 (I counted them) lines of irrelevant String concatenation before you see any code. That's mainly why I closed it - none but the most tenacious will bother to scroll down that far in the hope of finding anything useful. I still think it should be closed, but I'll leave it alone and respect the re-openers decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is indicating that this is a non-transitive comparison. I have to agree with Dave Newton's comment that it's hard to reason about this comparator. All the null-checking is confusing, but it seems like the order that things get compared in is not consistent. See [*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 12 (Consider Implementing Comparable):

> If a class has multiple significant fields, the order in which you compare them is critical. You must start with the most significant field and work your way down. If a comparison results in anything other than zero (which represents equality), you’re done; just return the result. If the most significant fields are equal, go on to compare the next-most-significant fields, and so on. If all fields are equal, the objects are equal; return zero.

Specifically, if you're comparing a null field to a non-null field your code is trying to go on and compare the next most significant field, that means you're taking a case where one field is null and the other isn't, so one ought to sort higher than the other, and you're treating them as if they are equivalent, yet you're going forward with comparing the next most significant fields.

Here's a comparator written to comply with Bloch's advice, that tries to clean up the null-checking; nulls get replaced with a low-sorting value so the ordering will be consistent:

```
class TestSortComparator implements Comparator<TestSort> {

    Double defaultIfNull(Double d) {
        return d == null ? Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY : d;
    }

    Integer defaultIfNull(Integer i) {
        return i == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : i;
    }

    String defaultIfNull(String s) {
        return s == null ? "" : s;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(TestSort o1, TestSort o2) {
        int pageComp = defaultIfNull(o1.getPage())
            .compareTo(defaultIfNull(o2.getPage()));
        if (pageComp != 0) return pageComp;
        int yComp = defaultIfNull(o1.getTopLeftY())
            .compareTo(defaultIfNull(o2.getTopLeftY()));
        if (yComp != 0) return yComp;
        int xComp = defaultIfNull(o1.getTopLeftX())
            .compareTo(defaultIfNull(o2.getTopLeftX()));
        if (xComp != 0) return xComp;
        return defaultIfNull(o1.getFormField())
            .compareTo(defaultIfNull(o2.getFormField()));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a small (yet critical) typo in `xComp`. It's always comparing `o2.getTopLeftX()` to itself (the first argument should of course be `o1.getTopLeftX`). This shows that even with the `defaultIfNull` helper methods, the implementation has enough verbosity to hide the actual _data_ being compared -- which in turn makes spotting the error more difficult. Minimizing the amount of code required for a proper `compareTo` implementation is what makes using `ComparisonChain` so appealing, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mick: fixed this, thanks. feel free to edit when you see things like this. and the guava approach is nice here.

Comment: Thank you Nathan.  This is what I was missing.  If one field was null but the other was not I was going on to the next comparison.  I rewrote the comparison and my test now succeeds with the data supplied.  Thank you for pointing out what I had overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

[Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982878/905488) correctly summarizes the problem with your `Comparator`; it is not obeying the contract with regards to the *transitivity* of comparisons. From the Javadocs of [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29):

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>
> ```
> ((compare(x, y) > 0) && (compare(y, z) > 0))
> ```
>
> implies
>
> ```
> compare(x, z) > 0
> ```

It can be difficult to write a null-safe comparator that compares multiple properties of an object -- even more difficult to write an implementation that's actually *correct*. Checking for nullness and keeping track of the value of the previous comparison makes the code clunky and verbose.

For the reasons mentioned above, it is preferable to utilize a proper framework to make the code more readable and less error-prone. Implementing a fluent `Comparator` is easy (and fun) with the help of [Google Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) [`ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) class. Here's how the `Comparator` looks like using `ComparisonChain`:

```
static class FluentComparator implements Comparator<TestSort> {

    @Override
    public int compare(TestSort o1, TestSort o2) {
        return ComparisonChain
                .start()
                .compare(o1.getPage(), o2.getPage(),
                        Ordering.natural().nullsFirst())
                .compare(o1.getTopLeftY(), o2.getTopLeftY())
                .compare(o1.getTopLeftX(), o2.getTopLeftX())
                .compare(o1.getFormField(), o2.getFormField())
                .result();
        }
   }
```

Note how fluently you can chain the different comparisons into a "one-liner". Also, each comparison in the chain is *lazily evaluated* (i.e. only if required), making the implementation efficient without needing to write multiple `return` statements. From the [docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#compare/compareTo.md):

> ComparisonChain performs a "lazy" comparison: it only performs comparisons
>   until it finds a nonzero result, after which it ignores further input.

You need to be careful with nullable properties, however. As `getPage()` can return `null` in your example data, we need to use the overload of [`compare`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html#compare%28T,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) which accepts nullable inputs and a strategy for handling `null`s (`null`s first in this case).

Comment: Mick with yours and Nathan's answers I now understand what was happening.  Your solution is much easier to read than the original code.  Thank you for posting it.  I did not know about comparison chain.